# Use of undeclared identifier with libcinder

Tags: c++, undeclared-identifier, osc, cinder

I've been working on this https://github.com/Morpheu5/SecondStudy-touch until the moment when Xcode decided to go bananas and stop compiling because of... well, I have no idea. It seems to me that this must be the result of some rookie mistake but I really can't see it.

The error it spits out is precisely

```
In file included from /Users/af6539/src/SecondStudy/xcode/../src/TouchPoint.cpp:1:
In file included from /Users/af6539/src/SecondStudy/xcode/../include/TouchPoint.h:4:
/Users/af6539/src/SecondStudy/xcode/../../cinder_0.8.5_mac/blocks/TUIO/include/TuioCursor.h:51:44: error: use of undeclared identifier 'osc'
    static Cursor createFromSetMessage( const osc::Message &message ) {
                                              ^
/Users/af6539/src/SecondStudy/xcode/../../cinder_0.8.5_mac/blocks/TUIO/include/TuioCursor.h:87:47: error: use of undeclared identifier 'osc'
    static Cursor25d createFromSetMessage( const osc::Message &message ) {
                                                 ^
```

which refers to the library I'm using, cinder, which includes TUIO and OSC. As I said, It was working, then I think everything started to go south when I began working on the whole MusicStroke* business, so those files may give some clues? If they do, I can't see them.

Comment: You're not missing a header file `#include`?

Comment: Where is osc::Message declared?

Comment: @Joachim if anything, I've included too many. I'm going throught them to make sure I don't get ring deps, but the #pragma once should still take care of that. doctorlove, as I said, they come from cinder, a third party library. You can get the source code from their web site, osc::Message is defined there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first suggestion I'd make is to roll back to a previous commit until you can successfully build. I'd also delete the build directory (or whatever the shared folder is if you're not using a relative 'Derived Data' path), as one possible explanation of what you saw is that a cached version of your compiled code was not showing the error, but then all of the sudden it was invalidated.

If I had to guess, without any sample code and only briefly skimming over your project, I would indeed say it is because a cyclical include. Try to forward declare what you can and #include from the .cpp.  For example, TouchTrace in MusicStrokeGesture.h can be forward declared...